# Background colour missing for content in div

Tags: html, css

The background color of the div is not showing up for the h1 and h3 content. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background: linear-gradient(#4C205C, #000000);
    margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header > h1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#header > h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <h3>Hello!</h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: [Working for me...](http://jsfiddle.net/V439d/)

Comment: I can see the background gradient color. What do you want to achieve specifically?

Comment: @mma Refere http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to create gradient bg for all browser

Comment: Its working for me also.. verified on Chrome.Which browser did u test on ?

Comment: actually what exactly is your requirement.??

Comment: Turns out I set the entire page's background to white in the whole CSS file and that's why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3Lz2d/)**

Your code works properly if you want to add background color for h1/h3 you need to specify css style for it.

```
#header > h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    background: red /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color then you have to use background property not color property because color property changes the color of text inside that div.

your CSS should be like this :

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background: linear-gradient(#4C205C, #000000);
margin: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

   #header h1{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }

#header h3{
     background:#FFFFFF;
     text-align: center;
}
```

Is this solves your problem if not comment..
Thank you!!